# jQuery code only applies on first element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to hide certain `<p>` elements when the value of an option form equals 'x'
The code works, but does only applie on the first element with the given ID.

My code is the following:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        var Privileges = jQuery('#form_1651_field_11');
    var select = this.value;
    Privileges.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '3') {
            $('#hide_on_call').css("display", "block");
        }
        else $('#hide_on_call').css("display", "none");
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input regeling" required="" style="width: 100%;">
        <option data-price="495.00" value="1"> Zelf betalen (€ 495,00)</option>
        <option data-price="0.50" value="3"> Factuur naar club of werkgever versturen (€ 0,50)</option>
    </select>

    <p id="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_12">Indien je club of werkgever betaald betaalt, vul dan onderstaande velden in:</label><br></p>
    <p id="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_14">Contactpersoon</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_14" id="form_1651_field_14" value="" label="Contactpersoon" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
    <p id="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_15">E-mailadres factuur</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_15" id="form_1651_field_15" value="" label="E-mailadres factuur" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
```

Comment: You cant have multiple tags with the same id that's wrong. use a class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. you are pointing to an element with `id="form_1651_field_11"` but it was not in your html.
2. you are using the same ID multiple times in your html. This is what classes are for. IDs are unique
3. you are using an obsolete syntax for jquery and a some unnecessary steps in your js.
4. your if/else block is missing some curly brackets

Also your logic seems weird for me. You are preselecting the option with `value="1"` (the p should be hidden) but the p are there. Only on change you hide them. Are you sure about it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#form_1651_field_11').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '3'){
      $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "block");
    }else{
      $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input regeling" required="" style="width: 100%;" id="form_1651_field_11">
  <option data-price="495.00" value="1"> Zelf betalen (€ 495,00)</option>
  <option data-price="0.50" value="3"> Factuur naar club of werkgever versturen (€ 0,50)</option>
</select>

<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_12">Indien je club of werkgever betaald betaalt, vul dan onderstaande velden in:</label><br></p>
<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_14">Contactpersoon</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_14" id="form_1651_field_14" value="" label="Contactpersoon" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_15">E-mailadres factuur</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_15" id="form_1651_field_15" value="" label="E-mailadres factuur" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant have the same id for multiple `<p>`, define a class,

In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a single attribute of type ID per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the id attribute is defined to be of type ID. In order to ensure that XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents, XHTML 1.0 documents MUST use the id attribute when defining fragment identifiers on the elements listed above. See the HTML Compatibility Guidelines for information on ensuring such anchors are backward compatible when serving XHTML documents as media type text/html.

```html
<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_12">Indien je club of werkgever betaald betaalt, vul dan onderstaande velden in:</label><br></p>
<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_14">Contactpersoon</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_14" id="form_1651_field_14" value="" label="Contactpersoon" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
<p class="hide_on_call"><label for="form_1651_field_15">E-mailadres factuur</label><br><input type="text" name="form_1651_field_15" id="form_1651_field_15" value="" label="E-mailadres factuur" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%"></p>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var Privileges = jQuery('#form_1651_field_11');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '3') {
        $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "block");
    }
    else $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "none");
});
});
```